# FtpWebRequest.Create and Uri throw an exception on one machine but not the other

Tags: c#

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp://10.107.1.40"));
```

This line of code I can run locally and not have an exception but when it's run on a clients machine it throws an exception.

On the clients machine I see:

> Type: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException Message:
>   Configuration system failed to initialize Source: System.Configuration
>   Stacktrace: at
>   System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.EnsureConfigurationSystem()

The inner exception is:

> Type: System.ArgumentException   Message: Illegal characters in
>   path.   Source: mscorlib   Stacktrace:    at
>   System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.HasIllegalCharacters(String[]
>   str)

I do not get this error locally and can not figure out what the problem is.

Comment: May be its .net framework issue , try to re-install it.

Comment: I further speratated the functions into:
    Uri uri = new Uri("ftp://10.107.1.40");
    FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(uri);

And the exception happens on the FtpWebRequest.Create

Comment: So we uninstalled the .NET Framework and re-installed it but that didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up having the customer upgrade from Windows Server 2003 to 2008 R2 which fixed the problem.